# phonegap ios) is it possible distinguish push notification that user clicked?

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

I am using phonegap push notification plugin and all seems work fine. push comes without any problem.

But the problem is there is nothing I can do when app is back-grounded.

multiple push notifications can arrive when app is backgrounded.  I can not expect which push

notification user going to click. Whatever notification user clicks, app will be resumed without

information of user selection. I have to trigger different events depanding on what nofitication

user selected. I need to know what notification user selected when app is resumed but don't

know how to... seems very tricky problem. is there anybody had same problem?

how did you guys handle this problem?

any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can`t get `all notification` information which fire during application is off or app. is in background but, you can fetch user info shortly receive notification in native iOS app.

please follow this [**application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786-CH3-SW18)
At first call of launch you can check for `options` and retrive the user-info.
for more info refer above link.

Answer (score 0):

never mind...

I thought window.plugins.pushNotifiction.getPendingNotification would return all pending

notifications which arrived while app is background.

But getPendingNotification function only returns the notification that user selected on

notification center or mobile screen.

well... seems nice..